# Shutting Off CELERY.BACKEND_CLEANUP on Amazon SQS

Tags: django, celery, amazon-sqs

I'm using Django with Celery. I need to turn off the celery.backend_cleanup that runs every day at 4 UTC. I've been looking at the documentation and can't find how to disable it. Below is my last try:

celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from django.conf import settings
from celery import Celery
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE",
                      "settings")

app = Celery('app')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'backend_cleanup': {
        'task': 'celery.backend_cleanup',
        'schedule': None,
        'result_expires': None
    },
}
```

I don't want this to run. How can I stop it?

UPDATE:

I also tried adding this to settings.py

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'backend_cleanup': {
        'task': 'celery.backend_cleanup',
        'schedule': 0,
        'result_expires': 0
    },
}
```

I know deleting task in db is an option, but if later on beat has to be restarted it creates the backend_cleanup again and it starts running it. I may not be the person maintaining this in the future, so I need this configured in the code not manually deleted from database.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few approaches you can try:

1. You could use a crontab definition that runs once far in the future, e.g.:

   ```
   app.conf.beat_schedule = {
       # Disable cleanup task by scheduling to run every ~1000 years
       'backend_cleanup': {
           'task': 'celery.backend_cleanup',
           'schedule': timedelta(days=365*1000),
           'relative': True,
       },
   }
   ```
2. You can try setting `app.backend.supports_autoexpire = True`, because this attribute is checked before the default backend_cleanup task is added ([src](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/28e0e30d51fc2666a71918bb9d95de4c15dbe7a6/celery/beat.py#L259)).
3. You can create a subclass your backend class and set supports_autoexpire = True

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Where would 'app.backend.supports_autoexpire=True' go? celery.py? Exactly like that? A one liner?

Comment: Yes, one line after `app.config_from_object(...)`. I haven't tried this myself, but from looking at the Celery source, it should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set the [`result_expires`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#result-expires) setting equal to `None`, but   define it as a global setting in your settings.py, and not a setting bound to a particular task (eg. `backend_cleanup` in your example).  You could also pass it into your app declaration directly.

The docs:

> **Default**: Expire after 1 day.
>
> Time (in seconds, or a timedelta object) for when after stored task tombstones will be deleted.
> A built-in periodic task will delete the results after this time (celery.backend_cleanup), assuming that celery beat is enabled. The task runs daily at 4am.
>
> A value of None or 0 means results will never expire (depending on backend specifications).

### Note that this only works with the AMQP, database, cache, Couchbase, and Redis backends, and not on SQS!

The [docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/sqs.html) on SQS:

> **Warning**
>
> Don’t use the amqp result backend with SQS.
>
> It will create one queue for every task, and the queues will not be collected. This could cost you money that would be better spent contributing an AWS result store backend back to Celery :)

Comment: When you say 'define it as global setting' what does that mean? Where? What do I write?  I'm not using celery <4. I'm using celery > 4.

Comment: @Silversail either in your settings.py with the namespace `CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES`, or you can pass it into your app declaration.

Comment: @Silversail what broker are you using, and what backend are you using?

Comment: Broker is SQS. Using db django_celery_results as backend.

Comment: @Silversail is changing your broker an option?  Apart from that, I think your only other option would be to write a result backend for SQS.

Comment: I'm not using SQS as a backend though..I'm using the database as backend.

Comment: @Silversail it doesn't matter which backend you use.  None of them support an SQS broker at the moment.

Comment: I don't think that is accurate. I'm using SQS with a database backend using django-celery-results. Everything works as it's supposed to, with the exception of the cancelling of the celery.backend.cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

You may be using django-celery-beat.  if so, you'll have to delete the scheduled task from your database.  You can do this through the django admin panel.

Comment: If I stop beat later and restart it, will it create the backend_cleanup task again in the database? Do I need to delete backend_cleanup again? I'm not going to be maintaining this in production, so I'm trying to configure it so that it doesn't run even if they bring a new beat.